# LVS LocalNode うまく動作しない問題

Tags: linux

Linux 4.1.6-1-ARCH x86_64 GNU/Linux環境で下記LVSドキュメントに掲示されたLocalNodeの例がうまく動作しないようです。
http://www.austintek.com/LVS/LVS-HOWTO/HOWTO/LVS-HOWTO.localnode.html
9.4. Testing LocalNode

手元の環境でrealserverのアドレスにloopbackアドレス127.0.0.1を指定しても、LocalNodeとして認識されない。

```
$ sudo ipvsadm -Ln
IP Virtual Server version 1.2.1 (size=4096)
Prot LocalAddress:Port Scheduler Flags
  -> RemoteAddress:Port           Forward Weight ActiveConn InActConn
TCP  172.20.10.5:8090 rr
  -> 127.0.0.1:8090               Route   1      0          0
```

↑ Localにならない

最近のカーネルに組み込まれたlvsにLocalNode機能が取り除かれたでしょうか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

linux-2.6.32 と linux-4.1.6 を比較すると、
linux-2.6.32/net/netfilter/ipvs/ip_vs_ctl.c::__ip_vs_update_dest() でローカルアドレスの場合に conn_flags に IP_VS_CONN_F_LOCALNODE をセットする箇所が、linux-4.1.6 ではなくなっています。

IP_VS_CONN_F_LOCALNODE がセットされないと
net/netfilter/ipvs/ip_vs_xmit.c::ip_vs_null_xmit() が使われないのですが、替わりに ip_vs_dr_xmit() の方でローカルアドレスの場合に ip_vs_null_xmit() と同様の処理をするようになっています。

変更された理由についてはわかりませんが、おそらく、設定時に IP_VS_CONN_F_LOCALNODE がセットされてそのまま、という仕様では不具合があって、実際の動作時にローカルアドレスかどうかを都度判定するようにしたのではないでしょうか。

Comment: コードレベルの確報ありがとうございます。;-)
フラグ表示がLocalNodeにならないしでも挙動としてLocalNodeのままってことですね。しかし、実際に動作確報したところ。クライアントからのSYNパケットにたいして、RSTでアクセスが拒否されました。iptables周りの設定が必要でしょうかね？

Comment: すみません、うまく出来ました。LocalNode動作するための前提条件としてサービスのListenアドレスにVIPを含めないといけない点に引っ掛かった。 改めて、ありがとうございます。;-)